# Why do some people not remember their dreams?

Tags: memory, psychology, dreams

Why does the ability to recall dreams varies greatly from person to person?

Why Some Remember Dreams, Others Don't 
https://www.livescience.com/38856-why-people-recall-dreams.html

I decided to ask my question because I read the above article, but the article is from August 13, 2013.  Bahar Gholipour is a staff writer for LiveScience. What have we learned about people's ability to recall their dreams since 2013?